# Front end / Reporting for database.com

Tags: reporting, database.com

I understand that there is no page layouts, visual force in database.com. I have a requirement to put a simple front end in a webpage ( not mobile or tablet) where in users can edit values in datbase.com objects. What are my options ? Any 3rd party tools which i can use or should i write a .net/ Java appl to query data from database.com using REST/ SOAP ?

Note : I also want to do some simple reporting on the data in database.com. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Right, Access would be REST/OAuth (or SOAP).  You can build the interface in nearly anything, depends on what you are comfortable in working with.

If you have Java experience, one of the quickest ways to get up and running is grabbing a Heroku account, install Eclipse and Heroku plugin for Eclipse, and then use the Spring MVC Force.com template.  It will create a Heroku Java app with the basics of REST and OAuth running, you basically just need to define a Connected App and put the credentials into the env variables.

However, there are also plenty of examples in other languages to get started with.